# ReactJs displaying objects passed in as props

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass an Object as props to a child component but when I log the data being passed it returns the following:`graphs:"[object Object]"`

Here is part of the code:

```
const test = {
        'data': [ 'data',{
          id: value.id,
          graph_title: value.graph_title,
          graph_metric1:value.graph_metric1,
          graph_metric2:value.graph_metric2,
          graph_type:value.graph_type,
          graph_category:value.graph_category
        }]
};

<Draggable className="drag-element" type="graphs" data={test}>TESTING</Draggable>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That's how objects are converted to strings in Javascript. Do you actually have any problems connected with react?

Comment: Can you please show the code being used to log the props?

Comment: @23k Im trying to access later to data like data.data.id

Comment: @Emmanuel what happens when you print out `data.data.id`...?

Comment: @jye265 `onDrop(data) {
      console.log(data)
  }`

Comment: @23k I get `undefined`

Comment: @Emmanuel Include more relevant code if there is any? Are you sure you aren't passing in a null object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't actually anything wrong with how the object is displayed, as that is the correct Javascript behavior. If you want to print out the actual data within the object, you'll have to access it like such:

`console.log(data.data.id)`